# Mess with async function with two threads in Play app

Tags: multithreading, scala, playframework, future

I am building a service method that suppose to build a CSV file. The titles of the file and results are coming from different threads.

```
def buildCsv(template: Template) : Future[TemporaryFile] = {

        val schemaFuture = dbViewSchemaRepository.findOneByTemplateId(template.id)
        val resultsFuture = checklistResultRepository.findAllByTemplateId(template.id)

        schemaFuture flatMap { optSchema =>
            val schema = optSchema match {
                case Some(sch : Schema) => sch
                case _ => throw UnexpectedException("Schema not found")
            }

            //get the titles
            val titles = buildTitles(schema)
            // create temp file
            val tempFile = TemporaryFile("test", ".csv")
            logger.info("Absolute path: " + tempFile.file.getAbsolutePath)

            // start writing results
            resultsFuture map { results =>
                results foreach { result =>
                    val resultRow = buildResultRow(result, schema)

                    tempFile.file.writeCsv(List(resultRow), ',', titles)
                }

                tempFile
            }

        }
    }
```

I've built a pretty simple test:

```
var dbViewSchemaRepo = mock[DbViewSchemaRepository]
            doReturn(Future(schema)).when(dbViewSchemaRepo).findOneByTemplateId(schema.templateId)

            var checklistResultRepo = mock[ChecklistResultRepository]
            doReturn(Future(List(result))).when(checklistResultRepo).findAllByTemplateId(schema.templateId)

            val template = mock[Template]
            template.id returns schema.templateId

            var srv = new ChecklistResultsExportService(dbViewSchemaRepo, checklistResultRepo)
```

When I run it I get an error:

> [error]    services.data.model.ChecklistSchema$Schema cannot be cast
>   to scala.Option (ChecklistResultsExportService.scala:38) [error]
>   services.data.ChecklistResultsExportService$$anonfun$buildCsv$1.apply(ChecklistResultsExportService.scala:38)

Line 38 is this:

```
schemaFuture flatMap { optSchema
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the way I was mocking the response from the repository objects. I should have done it like this:

```
doReturn(Future.successful(Some(schema))).when(dbViewSchemaRepo).findOneByTemplateId(schema.templateId)     
   doReturn(Future.successful(List(result))).when(checklistResultRepo).findAllByTemplateId(schema.templateId)
```

Seem to be working now.

Thanks.